# What content-type header has been set?

Tags: php, http-headers, content-type

How can I find out if this header: `header('Content-Type: application/json')` has been set during script execution?
`

Comment: `without resorting to setting a global flag...` means?

Comment: (1) Go to http://php.net/ ; (2) Type "header" in the search box and hit enter; (3) Browse the list of functions on the left-hand side; (4) Notice that among the functions there are `headers_ list` and `headers_sent`, which probably do what you want.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen If I could downvote comments I would downvote yours. (1) `headers_sent()` is not the solution to the questions (2) There are many *hidden treasures* in PHP. I code php since >10years and learn new functions almost every ~week. like `headers_list()`. thanks to this question (+1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[headers_list()](http://www.php.net/manual/function.headers-list.php) will return a list of headers to be sent to the browser / client. To determine whether or not these headers have been sent yet, use [headers_sent()](http://php.net/manual/function.headers-sent.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [`headers_sent`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php) or [`headers_list`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php) to determine if the headers were sent and which ones respectively.